# PostgreSQL + JDBC - authentication failed

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

*Update: It was a silly port configuration issue at my end - but answering below how I resolved it just in case it helps someone.*

In my spring boot application, running on Ubuntu 22 with PostgreSQL 14.7, I am getting a password authentication error when trying to connect to the postgresql server:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user
```

I have tried `password`, `md5`, `trust` and `scram-sha-256` as the settings in `pg_hba.conf`

```
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password

# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
#host    all             all             ::1/128                  password
```

I am able to connect with the username / password combination through command line. In case it matters, I am using `mvn spring-boot:run` command to run the spring boot application.

Somewhere I read that upgrading the postgresql driver to a specific version helps, so I have added this version in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <version>42.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How to identify the problem with the spring boot application connection and fix it? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

So first I tried checking error logs but no connection attempts were being logged. I came to know connections are not logged by default so turned them on with:

```
log_connections = on
```

in file `/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf` (in my case, on ubuntu linux)

Then, the error logs (in my case file `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log` on ubuntu), showed that jdbc connections were not reaching the server while normal socket connections were being shown.

That made me crosscheck the ports in the spring boot application and the postgresql conf file, and I found that the `application.xml` was using a different port to connect than the default one `5434` (but it was very similar looking to the default port, which is why I missed noticing it at a cursory inspection earlier).